# How can i resolve a lag problem with ChromiumWebBrowser in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, chromium

I have a windows form application for a virtual desktop, that have also to be used by an AI. The virtual desktop is a simple HTML page with some JS. I need to do periodically a screenshot of the desktop. ChromiumWebBrowser of CefSharp.WinForm doesn't implement it, unlike the one of CefSharp.OffScreen so i used an OffScreen web browser and a picture box to display the image of the web browser. The image is captured by a timer that tick every 10ms.
Here is the function that do the screenshot and replace it in the picturebox:

```
private void save(string path, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                bmp.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
                fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp1 = null;
        await chromeBrowser2.ScreenshotAsync().ContinueWith(
            async (task) =>
            {
                bmp1 = task.Result;
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            });
        if (bmp1 == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (pictureBox3.Image != null) pictureBox3.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox3.Image = bmp1.Clone(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp1.Width, bmp1.Height),
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
        save("C:\\Management/Finale.png", bmp1);
        bmp1.Dispose();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1_Click(sender, e);

    }
```

I redirect the event of the mouse on the picture box to the ChromiumWebBrowser using this code:

```
CefSharp.MouseEvent mouseEventt;
    private void pictureBox3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        mouseEventt = new MouseEvent(e.X, e.Y, CefEventFlags.None);
        pictureBox2.Location = new Point(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X + 1, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y + 1);

        chromeBrowser2.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseMoveEvent(mouseEventt, false);

    }


    bool test = false;
    private void pictureBox3_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && test == false)
        {
            test = true;
            chromeBrowser2.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 1, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        }


        if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && e.Clicks == 2)
        {
            test = true;
            chromeBrowser2.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y, MouseButtonType.Left, false, 2, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        }

    }

    private void pictureBox3_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( test == true)
        {
            test = false;
            chromeBrowser2.GetBrowser().GetHost().SendMouseClickEvent(System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X, System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y, MouseButtonType.Left, true, 1, CefEventFlags.LeftMouseButton);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
        }
    }
```

The code up here works but it causes a lag effect.
What did i do wrong? Thanks for the support :D

Comment: Um, maybe the `Thread.Sleep` calls?